Chrome extension side panel opening - clicking custom button and icon in extension bar are conflicting
I have created a chrome extension with side panel feature. But I have problems with opening side panel by click a button inside webpage and then in extension bar. Problem steps is like below:
If I reload page and click icon in extension bar in order to open side panel it opens. Then I close it in the same way
Then if I click an icon inside webpage I open it again and then I click it again and close it.
But after that if I click icon in extension bar it does not open. I have to reload the page.
How can I solve this problem ?
I use manifest version 3 and this is my code:
content.js file
const toggleSidePanel = () => {
  try {
     chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: 'toggleSidePanel' });
    } catch (e) {}
}
button.querySelector('#ainisa_icon').addEventListener('click', () => {
        toggleSidePanel();
    });

service-worker.js file
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(async (message, sender, sendResponse) => {
if (message.action === 'toggleSidePanel') {
    await handleSidePanelToggle(sender);
}  else if (message.action === 'closeSidePanel') {
    closeAllSidePanels(sender.tab.windowId, sender.tab.id);
} else if (message.action === 'openSidePanel') {
    await openAllSidePanels(sender.tab.windowId, sender.tab.id);
} else if (message.action === 'google') {
    await firebaseAuth();
} else {
    //
}

sendResponse({
    received: true
});
   return true;
});

const panelStates = new Map();
async function handleSidePanelToggle(sender) {
const tab = sender.tab;
const id = tab.windowId
const tabId = tab.id
const isPanelOpen = panelStates.get(id) || false;

  if (isPanelOpen === true) {
    closeAllSidePanels(id, tabId);
  } else {
    await openAllSidePanels(id, tabId);
  }
}
  async function openAllSidePanels(id, tabId) {
  panelStates.set(id, true);
  const isPanelOpen = panelStates.get(id) || false;
  chrome.sidePanel.setOptions({ enabled: true, path: "ainisa.html" });
  chrome.sidePanel.open({windowId:id}, () => {});
  const result = await chrome.storage.local.get(['user_token']);
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, { action: 'updateSidePanel', visible: isPanelOpen });

}

